# Explain coefficients in a multiple regression are the same as in simple regressions

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, econometrics, covariance-matrix

> Given the matrix of covariances, $M$ (below), three variables $X, Y, Z$, and a multiple regression $\hat{Z} = \frac{5}{4}X + \frac{4}{5}Y$:
>
> $$M=\begin{bmatrix}16 & 0 & 20\\0 & 25 & 20\\20 & 20 & 42\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Explain, why the coefficients,$b_X$ and $b_y$, in the simple
>   regressions $\hat{Z} = b_X*X$ and $\hat{Z} = b_y * Y$ would be equal
>   to $\frac{5}{4}$ and $\frac{4}{5}$. The first matrix column and row
>   represent $X$, the second - $Y$, the third - $Z$. So, for example,
>   $m_{1,3} = Cov(X, Z)$.

I guess the answer is connected to $Cov(\bullet)$, but I have no idea. Also, suppose we had an intercept in multiple and both simple regressions. What would be the relation between them? Just a sum $(\hat{a_M} = \hat{a_{S1}} + \hat{a_{S2}})$ or something more complex?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is homework?

Comment: Does look like homework.

Comment: It was taken from my friend's paper, yes. I'm just curious.

Comment: Homework would need a `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zeroes in the matrix mean that X and Y are uncorrelated, so a simple linear relationship holds.

Comment: why Y and Z are uncorrelated? Cov(Y, Z) is not zero.

Comment: Oh. I edited the question and realized why. X and Y do not have an effect on each other, so putting them together won't change a thing. Should've read the task more carefully.

Comment: Maybe my answer was a little misleading unintentionally, I've updated it. Good job for realizing it!